# How to make a AJAX JQuery on a JSP page to a Controller in Spring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I'm currently making two separate Ajax JQueries that will pass values from a google maps javascript page (Latitude, Longitude, Address of the location searched by the user) and to my controller class. However, I'm getting a different error for each request.

First AJAX Query results in the following error in the Google Developer Tools Console:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/results 403  (Forbidden)  jquery.min.js:4
```

The Code

```
  // This will send the lat/long values to one @RequestMapping method in the controller

  function sendLatLong(){

       $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
       $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

      var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
      console.log(Lat);

      var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
      console.log(Long);


       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/results",
       data: { latitude: Lat, longitude: Long }, // parameters
  })
 }
```

The Controller Code
    //The recieving method in the controller class

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST
         , produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}
         ,  consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
 )
 public @ResponseBody  String Submit(GardaStation gardaStation, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude) {

     //Print statment acting as a debug
     System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude + " from the client side");

    return "/";
 }
```

Second AJAX Query results in the following white label error in the browser

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

The JSP side Code

```
// I want to achieve the similar result as above but include an address and send it to a different method
function saveAreaToUser(){

           $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
           var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
           console.log(Lat);

           $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
           var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
           console.log(Long);

           $('.search_addr').val(results[0].formatted_address);
           var Address = results[0].formatted_address;
           console.log(Address);



        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/saveAreaToProfile",
         data: { latitude: Lat, longitude: Long, address: Address }, 
})
```

The Controller Code

```
 //The recieving method in the controller class
        @RequestMapping(value = "/saveAreaToProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAreaToProfile(@Valid Area area, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, 
            @RequestParam("address") String address) {

    //Print statment acting as a debug
    System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude + " Address:" + address + " from the client side");

    return "/savedAreas";
}
```

Is there a reason as to :
1) Why this is happening?
2) Different errors occur for more or less the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing the coordinates in data please send the data as JSON  use the @RequestBody and use JSON parser in your java code and get the coordinates

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body you can have look into this.

@RequestParam is only for parameter and data will send in Body.

Cheers